# Having troubles running R in VS code

Tags: r, visual-studio-code, terminal

I'm having issues with running my code in R after updating VS code. Every time I press Command Enter (Mac) to run it in the terminal I get the error posted below.

For every code I run, but if I put it in the terminal it reads it. I have been trying to find the issue to resolve. Same with python.

```
Error: unexpected numeric constant in "00~jhlibrary(dplyr)01
```

Comment: This sounds like a question to pose to the VS Code team. They have an [Issues](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues) folder on Github.

Comment: Can you try setting `"r.bracketedPaste": false`? (Although it would be a little bit strange if this works given that you're also experiencing the problem with Python.)